# Reference Calling Form from a Module

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a function within a module that opens my Home Page Form:

```
Function goto_home()
    Dim stDocName As String

    'DoCmd.Close acForm, "CallingForm.Name" , acSaveYes
    stDocName = "home_page"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
End Function
```

It's in a module because I have command buttons on all my forms that use the code instead of duplicating it within each Form Object.

The commented line in my code should close the calling form before the home page is opened. If I was doing it from a form object I would use `me.form.name` but you can't do that in a module.

Is there an equivalent module syntax that allows reference to the Calling Form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always pass the formname in the function e.g:

```
Function goto_home(frmName As String)

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    DoCmd.Close acForm, frmName , acSaveYes
    stDocName = "home_page"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

End Function
```

Then as you are calling this from each form, you can put the form's name in the call argument.